# Text.Parsec many parser won't fully parse a custom parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, eval

I'm having an issue in which my parser for if-blocks (and Do-While blocks because the problem is the same) won't terminate upon the parsing of the string "fi". An If-Block takes the form of:

```
if P -> p
[] Q -> q
fi
```

If I use `Text.Parsec`'s string parser to parse `"fi"` like how I used it to parse `"if"` to even enter the loop, the program halts. When I print out what should be evaluated its not even there so the program doesn't even enter the If-Block when it is ended with `"fi"`.

When I remove the parser that parses `"fi"` however, what occurs is that the program can run and the evaluation of the If-Block is as expected but I have to end the block with the same number of `"fi"` (or any string) as expressions within the block itself. If I don't end the block with the same number of `"fi"`'s, what happens is any statement after the block is evaluated infinitely. For example, a block which adds one to a running total if a variable is even would look like:

```
if ((x mod 2) = 0)-> r := r + 1
[] ((x mod 2) = 1)-> r := r + 0
fi
fi
```

And if there was a single `"fi"`, and I printed the value of r after the block, it would print r infinitely

```
if ((x mod 2) = 0)-> r := r + 1
[] ((x mod 2) = 1)-> r := r + 0
fi

print(r)

./Main prog
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

The issue is probably a misuse of the `spaces` function but I can't seem to get the parsing correct even when I remove all of the instances of spaces such that everything is on a single line concatenated together. Even when I do that, it won't accept `"fi"` in the Parser code but it will accept it if it's the same number as expressions when its removed.

```
parseIf :: Parser HStatement
parseIf = do
        try (string "if") <|> try (string "[]")
        spaces
        string "("
        cond  <- parseVals
        string ")->"
        spaces
        expr  <- many1 $ parseStatements
        spaces
        return $ If (cond, expr)


parseSelection :: Parser HStatement
parseSelection = do
        selection <- many1 parseIf
        spaces
        --try (string "fi")
        return $ Selection selection

parseStatements :: Parser HStatement
parseStatements = try (parseDo) <* spaces <|> try (parseSelection) <|> try (parsePrint) <|> try (parseEvalHVal)
```

Comment: This isn't a working example, so I can't test it, but my first guess is that something is failing with whitespace.  Specifically, when you parse `many $ try parseStatements`, it doesn't look like you're taking care of whitespace between multiple statements.

Comment: As @DDub says, `parseStatements` would parse something like `x := x + 1` but you want to parse `<many space>x := x + 1` . I think that something in the lines of  `many $ try (optional spaces >> parseStatements)` shoud work.

Comment: Right so I changed `many $ try parseStatements` to `many $ (spaces *> parseStatements <* spaces)` and added `spaces` after every line in each parser for example I added it before `x` in `parseArith` and the behaviour still persists

Comment: The behaviour is strange because I tried `many $ try (optional spaces >> parseStatements)` and the behaviour remained the same but the thing is I'm able to execute expressions like `x := x + 1` in sequence without a loop no problem

Comment: @JiangShi can you try without indentation within `Do-Od`? just to check if the problem is that. Another thing `spaces` isn't on `Text.Parsec`, how is it defined?

Comment: @Ismor I'm really sorry I may have gotten confused regarding `spaces`. I am using `Text.ParserCombinations.Parsec` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Char.html.               I tried it without the indentation and it works! I'm happy it works but now I'm really confused as to why it doesn't work with `Do-Od` and further more, now the entire program after the guard is part of the loop if that makes any sense.

Comment: @JiangShi I think, there isn't enough info in the code snipet you posted. For example you have a comment saying `parseEvalHVal` is equivalent to `parseArith` but. `parseArith` is not parsing the operator `:=` (afaik) so I think it should fail parsing somthing like `x := x + 1`. Could you edit the question and add the definition of relevant parser, working examples, not working examples, and how indentation affects. Also, errors shown by `parsec`.

Comment: @Isomer Yeah sure, I'll add it all in now

Comment: @Isomer I added everything there!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you switch the line from `expr  <- many1 $ try (spaces >> parseStatements)` instead of, say, `expr <- many $ try (spaces >> parseStatements)`?

Comment: No real reason, might have just been a typo

Comment: @Isomer Interestingly when the `parseDo` function starts with `string "Do"`, I still get the right output (not counting that the whole program becomes a part of the loop)

Comment: @JiangShi honestly, I don't know what's going on. Try to print the AST of your program instead of evaluating it. Also, which function reads your program as a whole? I see `Parse HStatement` and `Parse Val`, but there isn't a `Parse HProgram`.

Comment: Can you update your post to include a complete, runnable example?  That means including the definitions of the data types and the various custom `parse***` functions you've written.  Ideally, it would be a _minimal_ example (where you remove bits that work fine while keeping everything runnable).